# 32 hexadecimal digit string output

Tags: vb.net, hex, check-digit

Hey all I have the following 32 hexadecimal digit string:

```
0x80000000000000003F64000000000000
```

And when I need to take that number above and look up something with it I need it to be searchable in this type of format:

```
0000-0000-3F64-0000-S-0000-0000-R
```

The *official* format it needs to be in order to search is explained like this:

> Format:

```
NNNN-NNNN-NNNN-NNNN-X
   or
NNNN-NNNN-NNNN-NNNN-X-NNNN-NNNN-Y
   or
NNNN-NNNN-NNNN-NNNN
```

> where N are hexadecimal digits, X and Y are check digits.
>
> 16 hexadecimal digit followed with a check character (using Arabic numerals 0 to 9 and letters A to Z), followed by an 8 hexadecimal digit version segment, followed with a check character (using Arabic numerals 0 to 9 and letters A to Z).
>
> Defined in ISO 15706-2 Annex D. The ISAN.

**ROOT**: *0000-0000-3F64*

> Tree segment of **4 digit** hexadecimal values separated with a hyphen "-"

**EpisodeOrPart**: *0000*

> One segment of **4 digit** hexadecimal values.

**Check1**: *S*

> **One digit** made of a decimal value from 0 to 9 or an upper case charater from A to Z.

**Version**: *0000-0000*

> Two segments of **4 digits** hexadecimal values separated with an hyphen "-".

**Check2**: *R*

> **One digit** made of a decimal value from 0 to 9 or an upper case character from A to Z.

And I am not really sure how to go about converting what I have to the needed format so any help would be great!

**Note: The "-S" and the "-R" can be removed. Those are random computer generated algorithms that add those which, as you see in the example above, are not needed in the search if you do not have them available. So really I would only be interested in getting the format to be "0000-0000-3F64-0000-0000-0000".**

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you want, but ...

This function removes the `0x` from the beginning:

```
Private Function format(ByVal str As String) As String
    str = str.Substring(10)
    For i As Integer = 20 To 4 Step -4
        str = str.Insert(i, "-")
    Next
    Return str
End Function
```

Returns `0000-0000-3F64-0000-0000-0000` from `0x80000000000000003F64000000000000`

For just 32 characters hex without the `0x` prefix, this function:

```
Private Function format(ByVal str As String) As String
    str = str.Substring(8)
    For i As Integer = 20 To 4 Step -4
        str = str.Insert(i, "-")
    Next
    Return str
End Function
```

Returns `0000-0000-3F64-0000-0000-0000` from `80000000000000003F64000000000000`

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what you want... where does the 8 go?

Here's is some code that may help...

```
'32 hex digits = 16 bytes (128 bits)'
Dim s As String = "0x80000000000000003F64000000000000" 
'simple reformat'
Dim s_sf As String = s.Substring(10, 4) & "-" & s.Substring(14, 4) & "-" & s.Substring(18, 4) & "-" & s.Substring(22, 4) & "-S-" & s.Substring(26, 4) & "-" & s.Substring(30, 4) & "-R"
MsgBox(s_sf)
'Convert hex string to byte 0x3F = 63 decimal
Dim b As Byte = Convert.ToByte("3F", 16)
MsgBox(b.ToString)
'Convert byte to Hex string 63 decimal = 0x3F
Dim s_hex As String = Hex(63)
MsgBox(s_hex)
```